# Solve the following number theory problem with 2 variables

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratics

Let there be 
$$a,b∈ \Bbb Z$$
Demonstrate that there exist no solutions for the following equation 
$$a^2-3b^2=-1$$

Comment: This is immediate if you write this equation $\mod{3}$.

Comment: A more detailed explination would be appreciated.I dont know how to use the modulo operations properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment by Crostul,$$a^2-3b^2=-1 \Rightarrow a^2+1=3b^2$$

Now $3$ divides R.H.S.
But 
for any $a$, $$a \equiv 0,1,2 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow a^2 \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow a^2+1 \equiv 1, 2 \pmod 3$$

So $3$ does not divide L.H.S.

Hence, no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a and b are both even.
Then $ { 4k }^{ 2 } = 3(4q^2)-1$  and so $2(2k^2)=2(6q^2)-1$ and... $2(x)=2(y)-1$ odd can't be even.
Let's assume now a and be are both odd.
Then $(2k+1)^2=3(2q+1)^2  -1$
So $2(2(k^2+k)) +1 = 2(6q^2+6q+1)$ and... $2(x) +1 = 2(y)$ even can't be odd

The last one I let you solve it on your own.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't flipped the roles of "odd" and "even"? If $a$ is odd, then it should be $2k+1$, not $2k$. Also, it is better to format your formulae using MathJax.

Comment: You're right. MathJax has the same notation as Latex?

Comment: Yes, the same notation. It looks much better now.

Comment: The problem is that there are mistakes in your answer. For instance, when you multiply ${ 2k }^{ 2 } = 3(2q^2)-1$ by $2$, the last term should become $-2$, not $-1$, which completely invalidates your answer.

Comment: Wow. My bad, I was not multiplying by 2. I think now it's right